# How to split math calculations in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have mathematical calculations in div tag, like that:

```
13*7=91
```

So how to split and parse data?

and it will stored in variables like that:

```
var A = 13;
var Operation = '*';
var B = 7;
var Result = 91;
```

please tell me how to make that :)

Comment: First thing would be to write some code. You should try by yourself and then come back here if you get stuck. Be aware that this probably won't be as simple as you expect...

Comment: Operation should be `*`?

Comment: Please enter more information. Question is unclear

Comment: yes this is true Operation must be *

Comment: I don't have any code without this: <div class="history">13*7=91</div>

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "parsing", and in particular you want to parse arithmetic expressions. That's a fascinating topic and it's really valuable to learn ways to do that, but it's a significant topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way of doing it, simply using **RegExp**.

The first one is `/[0-9]+/g` to take the operands and the result numbers and the second one is `/[0-9]+(.)[0-9]+/` to extract the operator, then I print the result in a diplay `p` elemnt:

```js
var str = document.getElementById("calcul").innerText;

var re = /[0-9]+/g;
var re2 = /[0-9]+(.)[0-9]+/;
var operands = str.match(re);
var operator = str.match(re2)[1];
var A = operands[0];
var B = operands[1];
var result = operands[2];

var display = document.getElementById("display");
display.innerHTML = "var A = " + operands[0] + "<br>var B = " + operands[1] + "<br>var result = A" + operator + "B =" + result;
```

```html
<div id="calcul">
  13*7=91
</div>
<br>Calculation results :
<p id="display">

</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split it first by `=` sign, and then by possible math signs, for example:

```
var s = '13*7=91';
var a = s.split('=');
var b = a[0].split(/[\+\-\*\/\^%]/);
var A = b[0];
var B = b[1];
var Operation = a[0].replace(A,'').replace(B,'');
var Result = a[1];

console.log(A+Operation+B+'='+Result);
```

Output:

```
13*7=91
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try something like this:
Make a regular expression that detects the numbers separated by anything (+, *, -, /, =, etc).
Make that regular expression detects the separating elements.
Then execute eval() in javascript. Be careful with this.

When you have a piece of code show us and we can help you better.

Good luck.